# Can firstHour be called like a method in FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

When creating the fullCalendar I can set firstHour and have it scroll to that hour, but I only want this to happen when the current day is today. If the user goes to the next day, I want the scrollbar to be at the top of the container, but if they come back to today I want it to go to the firstHour again.

Is there a way to call firstHour like a method? Or is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about the dayView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check what day you are currently showing with the `viewDisplay` callback. But as far as I know you can't change the firstHour option after you have initialized the calendar. You will have to destroy it and then build it again...

```js
viewDisplay: function(view) {
    if (view.start.toDateString() === new Date().toDateString()){
        alert('Currently showing today!');
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not the best solution, but it will work. Thanks.